# Sonarlint not working in visual studio code

Tags: sonarlint-vs

I have installed sonarlint plugin in visual studio code but I am getting this error

[image]

I have set the java environment variable and created a sample java file which is working fine. I can't figure out where is the issue.

Kindly help me to sort out this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: same here, doesn't work for VSCode, maybe we need to find another linter